# Wordpress loop the wp query contents in common div

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am looping `wp_query` and I am getting each row in common `ul` `li`. I want each column separate in a `div`

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="js-filter">
    <?php
    $get_parent_cats = [
        'taxonomy'     => 'category',
        'hierarchical' => TRUE,
        'orderby'      => 'term_order',
        'parent'       => '0' //get top level categories only
    ];

    $all_categories = get_categories( $get_parent_cats );//get parent categories

    foreach ( $all_categories as $single_category ) {
        //for each category, get the ID
        $catID = $single_category->cat_ID;

        //category name & link
        echo '<h1>' . $single_category->name . '</h1>';

        $query = new WP_Query( [
            'post_type' => 'jobs',

            'showposts'        => - 1,
            'category__in'     => [ $single_category->term_id ],
            'category__not_in' => 6,
        ] );

        // Posts for the parent category (should be none)
        while ( $query->have_posts() ):$query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="job_position">
                <ul>
                    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="job_location">
                <ul>
                    <li><?php the_field( 'location' ); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="read_more">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();

    } //end of categories logic ?>

</div>
```

What I want as the markup:

```
<div class="job_container">
    <h3>marketing</h3>
    
    <div class="job_position">
        <ul>
            <li>job position</li>
            <li>job position</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="job_location">
        <ul>
            <li>job location</li>
            <li>job location</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="read_more">
        <ul>
            <li><a>job readmore</a></li>
            <li><a>job readmore</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? Curious as it looks like you are separating the job information into different `divs`? Is there a layout you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work

```
<div class="js-filter">
    <?php
        $get_parent_cats = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'orderby' => 'term_order',
        'parent' => '0' //get top level categories only
    );

        $all_categories = get_categories( $get_parent_cats );//get parent categories

        foreach( $all_categories as $single_category ){
            //for each category, get the ID
            $catID = $single_category->cat_ID;

            //category name & link
            echo '<h3>' . $single_category->name . '</h3>';
            
            
            $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'jobs',
            
                'showposts' => -1,
                'category__in' => array($single_category->term_id),
                'category__not_in' => 6 ,
            ) );
            
            ?>
            <div class="job_position">
                <ul>
                <?php 
                    // Posts for the parent category (should be none)
                    while( $query->have_posts() ):$query->the_post();
                ?>
                <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="job_location">
                <ul>
                    <?php 
                        // Posts for the parent category (should be none)
                        while( $query->have_posts() ):$query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <li><?php the_field('location') ; ?></li>
                    <?php
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="read_more">
                <ul>
                    <?php 
                        // Posts for the parent category (should be none)
                        while( $query->have_posts() ):$query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> </li>
                    <?php
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
 </div>
```